# Having line.new start at the begining of the trading day

Tags: pine-script

How to have `line.new`’s x1 and x2 start and end at a specific time ?
I’d like x1 to start at the beginning of the trading day (8.30am UTC+8) and x2 to stop at the end (3:50am UTC+8). Therefore the lines should only appear for the current day.

Any help ? Thanks !

Here's my code :

```
var step = syminfo.mintick*500

if barstate.islast
    for counter = 0 to 5 - 1
        stepUp = ceil(close / step) * step + (counter * step)
        line.new(bar_index[1], stepUp, bar_index, stepUp, extend=extend.right, color=color.blue, width=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this snippet for your needs:

```
//@version=4
study("")

var line1 = line.new(na,na,na,na)
period  = input("1", "Period", input.resolution)
session = input("1400-1800", "Session", input.session)
inSession = time(period, session, "UTC+00")

if not inSession[1] and inSession
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Start")
    line.set_x1(line1, bar_index)
    line.set_y1(line1, high)
    line.set_y2(line1, high)


if inSession[1] and not inSession
    label.new(bar_index, high, "End")
    line.set_x2(line1, bar_index)
```